# How can I properly respond with a null value to an SNMP (2c) GetRequest?

Tags: snmp, nullable, mib

I am developing an SNMP (2c) agent for a sensor product. I'm just learning about SNMP and MIB formats and struggling to represent a particular value that could be unknown.

For example, I've defined a temperature `OBJECT-TYPE` as an Integer32 but sometimes the value is not available or unknown. If I respond with a null value, the SNMP manager times out*. I would prefer to use a null value when the temperature value is unknown or not available, instead of agreeing upon some specific value to mean the same thing.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Does SNMP v2c/MIB support a data type that is analogous to a nullable integer?
2. If so, what is the proper way to denote this in the MIB?

<sub>* *I am using [MG-SOFT's MIB Browser](http://www.mg-soft.si/mgMibBrowserPE.html) to get values as a testing method. If the value is null, it times out (even though the agent responded). If the value is an integer, it works as expected. I am using [nSoftware IP*Works! SNMP library](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/snmp/) to develop the agent.*</sub>

Comment: I'm pretty sure the protocol does not allow for a 'nullable' variable in the way that you want.  Why not just have another BOOL read-only variable called "TemperatureInitialised", "TemperatureReady" or similar?

Comment: @Ian That is what I may need to do, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome @JYelton.  Actually a status variable for the sensor, where you've defined an enumeration for possible states, would be better practice than a boolean value.

Comment: Did you know how to respond with an error status? That's just the way to go.

Comment: @Lex I think I prefer your suggestion. Responding with an error versus adding additional data points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting from comment:

You should not be doing this. OID values should always be singular they should not be dynamically changed, if someone will use a mibfile for this it will be incorrect and misleading for the person who is implementing communication protocol for this sensor. The correct way to do it is to have 2 OIDs one with the value and another with the status of the sensor.

Answer (score -1):

In experimenting, I've had some success dynamically changing the SNMP agent object type:

```
int? temperature = ReadTemperature();
snmpAgent.Objects[i].Value = temperature.ToString();
snmpAgent.Objects[i].ObjectType = temperature.HasValue ? SNMPObjectTypes.otInteger : SNMPObjectTypes.otNull;
```

When performing a GetRequest with a MIB browser, it appears to handle both cases. Even though the MIB doesn't specify that the particular OID can be null, just `SYNTAX Integer32`, it seems to work. Various SNMP managers will probably behave differently.

*(This example is specific to IPWorks SNMP Agent.)*

Comment: You should not be doing this. OID values should always be singular they should not be dynamically changed, if someone will use a mibfile for this it will be incorrect and misleading for the person who is implementing communication protocol for this sensor. The correct way to do it is to have 2 OIDs one with the value and another with the status of the sensor

Comment: @Vajura If you were to post this as an answer I could give it an upvote and even be swayed to change my implementation. There's just so little information on this dinosaur tech!